# Gitosis setup, fatal error on initial clone of gitosis-admin

Tags: ssh, debian, hosting, git

I'm stuck. After setting up gitosis, cloning gitosis-admin for the first time results in the following:

> ```
> $ git clone ssh://git@myserver.com:gitosis-admin.git
> Initialized empty Git repository in c:/path/to/my/repo
> Using username "git-upload-pack 'git".
> fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
> ```

Anyone ever experience this problem? Troubleshooting ideas?

Comment: You could try gitolite. This is a new project based on the idea of gitosis, but it's actively maintained. gitosis hasn't really been worked on since 2008.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out this was an SSH issue. Disabling password authentication on the server revealed that running the clone command with git-bash was failing with the following output:

```
FATAL ERROR: Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available
```

Stumbling upon this [thread](http://markmail.org/message/u3md42mwtvytlyb2) led me in the right direction. My GIT_SSH env var was set to use plink. Because of this, git used putty to connect via ssh (despite me expecting openSSH)

Gitosis requires the use of an agent to store your keys for exchange. I started up pageant and BAM, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Actually your real problem was the `git clone ssh://git@myserver.com:gitosis-admin.git` being in an invalid format. You should of either removed the `ssh://` or changed the last `:` to a `/`. You probably fixed this on a future attempt without realizing it.